# Nhibernate Joining Tables to check similar fields from two tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Sorry in advance, if my question is stupid. I am working on Nhibernate query on ProductReview objects where some of it could be linked to AffiliateProduct. So basically like this.

```
public class ProductReview    
{   
    public virtual decimal? Price { get; set; }    
    public virtual AffiliateProduct AffiliateProduct { get; set; }
}

public class AffiliateProduct        
{
    public virtual decimal? Price { get; set; }
}

ProductReview productReview = null;    
AffiliateProduct affiliateProduct = null;    

var queryOver = _session.QueryOver(() => productReview)
            .JoinAlias(x => x.AffiliateProduct, 
                      () => affiliateProduct, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

The following line is where I couldn't get my head around.

```
queryOver = queryOver.Where(() => productReview.Price>= 100 || affiliateProduct.Price >= 100);
```

The last price filter query is not what I would to get. What I would like to get is "If ProductReview object is mapped to AffiliateProduct, check with the price from AffiliateProduct. If not, check with ProductReview's price."

I am new in nhibernate, could anyone please guide is there anyway to check around the last filter. Is it Criteria that I have to use? I am scratching my head. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
queryOver = queryOver.Where(() => (affiliateProduct.Price != null && affiliateProduct.Price >= 100) || productReview.Price>= 100);
```

Comment: thanks indeed and I am giving it ago as you suggested and will let you know. cheers

Comment: I just tested it. it is behaving same as mine. Coz of || (OR) it is still checking for both. I slightly twisted the 2nd bit of what you suggested and it works perfectly now. thanks very much.

Comment: queryOver = queryOver.Where(() => (affiliateProduct.Price != null && affiliateProduct.Price >= 100) || (productReview.AffiliateProduct == null && productReview.Price >= 100));

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use `QueryOver`? LINQ might serve you better:

```
var results = 
    _session
        .Query<ProductReview>()
        .Where(r => (r.AffiliateProduct != null && r.AffiliateProduct.Price > =100) || r.Price >= 100)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you and I am giving it ago as you suggested with LINQ and will let you know. thanks indeed.